# What are the deities available to Adventurers League clerics?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, dnd-adventurers-league, religions-and-deities

I've been going through Google and I can't seem to find a legal deity listing for [Adventurers League](http://dnd.wizards.com/playevents/organized-play).

What are the deities available to clerics? Are there any constraints, like choosing from Forgotten Realms or Greyhawk settings?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**, there are restrictions. Check with your season to make sure there are no exceptions. The general guideline is:

From the "adventure league's players guide" by WotC in the Section:

"Part 1: Characters" => "Character Creation" => "Choose a class":

> **Deities**. D&D Adventurers League storylines are set
>   in the Forgotten Realms, and as such, people worship
>   the deities of that world. If you would like your character
>   to worship a deity, you can choose one from the list of Forgotten Realms or nonhuman deities presented in appendix B of the Player’s Handbook or the D&D
>   basic rules. Clerics and characters with the Acolyte
>   background must choose a deity from that list. If you’re
>   a cleric, you can choose one of the deity’s suggested
>   domains or the Life domain. The Death domain is not
>   allowed unless that rules option is available for your
>   storyline season.

Comment: The (apparent) latest version of the Player's Guide (from the [AL Player's Pack](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack) states: "***Deities.*** If your character worships a deity, those deities listed in the Deities of the Forgotten Realms and Nonhuman Deities tables in the PHB or any deity listed in the [PHB, EEPC, SCAG, Volo's, or Xanathar's] are  available. While paladins don’t have to worship a deity, clerics do. If your deity doesn’t include suggested domains in the resource in which it is found, only the Life domain is available."

Comment: It's under "Step 4. Describe Your Character" now.